# Festival of Time Secrets

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

In The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask, there is a piece of art found during the Grandmother side quest that sheds a bit of information on the past history of Termina.

[image: An artwork depicting the Festival of Time as found in Majora's Mask]

Clearly this depicts the Festival of Time, the wondrous carnival held every year in celebration of the harvest. Several interesting bits are hidden within, such as numerous Giant-inspired masks, Tingle, and a puppy.

More interesting to me, however, is the piece of paper found on the tower with some cryptic lettering on it, as well as a strangely-out-of-place Odolwa's Mask, the mask of the boss of Woodfall Temple. The lettering seems to closely resemble some Ancient Hylian fonts, though there are some strange differences. I was unable to translate it.

My twofold question (or perhaps twinmold?): What might the significance of Odolwa's mask just hanging out here be? And, more pertinently, is the Terminian text translatable, and if so, what does it say?

Comment: Worth looking at (though I don't see this specific image addressed): https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hylian_Language_Translations/Majora%27s_Mask

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't read too much into it. Nintendo weren't really ones to hide secrets about the lore of their games anywhere

Comment: @Ben Audacious thing to say about Majora's Mask with a name like this. ;-)

Comment: @SF. [I'm sure I have no idea what you mean....](https://64.media.tumblr.com/249af37960cd9e9e440060a1c2dfbed7/tumblr_nufos70dRj1s6rdz2o1_640.gifv)

Comment: It also looks a bit like "山こ GTP".

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest alphabet I found:

[image]

Here's the original text, as well as flipped in all directions with the characters I think match the most:

[image]

It's katakana, so these should represent some foreign words and not Japanese.

Maybe someone else finds a better match.